# Why am i getting same output In Logistic Regression and Support Vector Machine

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, logistic-regression

I have run my code in Jupyter Notebook(using Anaconda) as well as in separate files in Pycharm, but still, I am getting the same output for Logistic Regression and Support Vector Machine using (the 'linear' kernel).
Accuracy, Recall, Precision as well as the Confusion Matrix, all are having the same output.
ROC curves differ in both cases, so does the AUC.
At first, all code was in one Jupyter Notebook getting the same output, I put each algorithm in a separate notebook but got the same result. I copied the code in Pycharm in separate files, but still getting the same output. Can the Output be completely same for both?
Here is the code for Logistic Regression:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.1,random_state=1)
lr = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
lr.fit(X_train,Y_train)
Y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred))
print("Precision:",metrics.precision_score(Y_test, Y_pred))
print("Recall:",metrics.recall_score(Y_test, Y_pred))
Y_pred_proba = lr.predict_proba(X_test)[::,1]
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(Y_test, Y_pred_proba)
print("AUC:",auc)
```

and below is the code for SVM

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.1,random_state=1)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear',probability=True)
clf.fit(X_train,Y_train)
Y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred))
print("Precision:",metrics.precision_score(Y_test, Y_pred))
print("Recall:",metrics.recall_score(Y_test, Y_pred))
Y_pred_proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[::,1]
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(Y_test, Y_pred_proba)
print("AUC:",auc)
```

the following is the output of Linear Regression

```
Accuracy: 0.8709677419354839
Precision: 0.8235294117647058
Recall: 0.9333333333333333
13 3 1 14
AUC: 0.9208333333333334
```

Output for SVM

```
Accuracy: 0.8709677419354839
Precision: 0.8235294117647058
Recall: 0.9333333333333333
13 3 1 14
AUC: 0.925
```

Comment: Maybe because you are using variable clf to predict in both the cases ? So, you are basically doing SVM in both the cases.

Comment: Compare the actual probabilities they predict.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be completely same score on two different classifier,

I suspect from two things below;

1. It depends on data. How many sample do you have and what is your data? Is it categorical?
2. Why you are using only 10% of the data as test data? It is too less. You should increase your data to predict better.
3. random_state=parameter    => It helps to shuffle test
4. You should use predict method instead of predict_oba

I believe these observation can help you.